# Ident textbox with label above it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three textboxes, which are on one line.
The first textboxes has label above it, the second one doesn't, which results in broken indentation. How can I fix this ?

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Line Height</label>
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Ime" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Ime" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Padding Bottom</label>
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Ime" />
    </div>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/quyB6/77/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Line Height</label>
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Ime">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Ime">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Padding Bottom</label>
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Ime">
    </div>
</form>
```